# Erro TEdit / TDBEdit

Tags: delphi, pascal

Estou com um pequeno problema. Quando eu uso o `TEdit` no meu formulário, as teclas que eu digito são capturadas pela caixa de texto (o que é normal!), Porém quando eu uso um `TDBEdit`, as teclas não são capturadas pela caixa de texto. Alguém já passou por isso e sabe como me ajudar?

> **IDE**: Estou usando o Delphi 10.1 Berlin
>
> **Banco**: Firebird 3.0 (Ibexpert).

Comment: Você ligou o DataSet e o DataFiled do TDBEdit?

Comment: Muitíssimo obrigado! Foi perfeito sua resposta. Solucionou meu problema. Abraços amigo!

Comment: De nada, todos os componentes de banco precisam esta ligados no banco. kkkkk

Comment: @GabrielLocalhost poderia transformar o comentário em resposta né?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você ligou o `DataSet` e o `DataField` do `TDBEdit`?

Um para o componente de tabela (`DataSet`) e outro para o campo (`DataField`), todos os componentes de banco precisam estar ligados no banco.

Comment: Oi amigo liguei sim. Consegui resolver o problema. Não tirei ainda a pergunta do site porque não sei se tem como e se tem não sei como sou novo aqui. De qualquer forma agradeço imensamente.

Comment: de boas, só transformei o meu comentário em resposta